# How can I properly config the uncss in grunt?

Tags: css, gruntjs, uncss

I've tried to configure uncss using grunt

I've installed

```
npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev
npm install grunt-processhtml --save-dev
```

---

## Configuration

```
uncss: {
    dist: {
        files: { 'dist/css/clean.css': ['index.php'] }
    }
}
```

at the end I load them in and register a default task like this :

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss', 'processhtml']);
```

---

## Result

When I run `grunt`

at the end I keep seeing :

Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task

> Fatal error: PhantomJS: Cannot open about:blank

---

## Update

I added :

```
processhtml: {

    dist: {

        files: {

            'index.php': ['index.php']
        }
    }
}
```

Still get the same error after running `grunt`

Answer (score 1):

If this is all of your code, you are not referencing any stylesheets to remove code from. All you are doing is telling grunt where the cleaner file should go, and to remove any unused css from index.php. However, it doesn't know where the styles for index.php live, so it has nothing to do... You need to actually configure your processhtml and tell uncss which stylesheets you would like to clean up.

Read the directions friend:

[grunt-uncss github readme.md](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss)

Comment: I added the configure for processhtml, and still have the same error message. Did I still forget to do anything elses ?

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem with my project and the solution is [here](https://github.com/giakki/uncss/issues/150):
You need update the uncss module, remember grunt-uncss is only a way to use uncss node package. In my case my version of that was in 0.12.1 and updating that package the problem was fixed. Let me know if this help you.